# angular ngAfterViewInit element focus not workin

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

When loading a component, I want you to focus on the first element after initialization. I found a tutorial for this, but it doesn't want to work for me.

https://davidmcintosh.medium.com/auto-focusing-an-angular-input-the-easy-way-part-1-dcb1799e025f

But if I put it in a timer that is 0 then it works great. But I don't want to use timer.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    timer(0).subscribe(() => this.firstElement.nativeElement.focus());
}
```

Why do I need a timer with such a ridiculous value?

Here is my HTML  code:

```
<p class="news-title" tabindex="0" #firstElement>{{ 'news.title' | translate }}</p>
<ul class="news-list" role="list">
    <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-1' | translate }}</li>
    <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-2' | translate }}</li>
    <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-3' | translate }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is executed after the usual change detaction cycle has been completed. If you perform some status update in `ngAfterViewInit` you will get the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterIthasBeenChecked` error. So almost everyone performs a variant of a settimeout(..., 0) in it to perform extra actions. In this particular case, given you're not performing actions changing the status of the component, I would say there is no read difference in using `timer(0)`. Btw, `focus` usually is performed on `input` elements. What do you expect trying it on a `<p>`?

Comment: I need focus because accessibility.

Comment: Well, it's quite normal in JavaScript to need to use a `settimeout(function, 0)`. It is common practice and it has always been. You can experiment with the options of `ViewChild` in your component (not present in the snippet you posted). I suppose you just cannot call focus in the same tick in which the DOM node has been created, but this is just a conjecture.

Comment: I'd suggest instead looking at the [angular a11y accessibility cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview) directives made to handle this like `cdkFocusInitial` instead of the half baked stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working for me, since your `<p>` tag is static which would always be there, you can query `viewChild` with `{static: true}`, that case it would query the element before change detaction, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions68005047angular-ngafterviewinit-element-focus-1?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

```
  @ViewChild('firstElement', {read: ElementRef, static: true})
  firstElement?: ElementRef<unknown>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    (this.firstElement?.nativeElement as any).focus();
  }
```

Better solution would be use material's A11y CDK [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/api), see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions68005047angular-ngafterviewinit-element-focus-not-work?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<p cdkTrapFocus="false" cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture class="news-title" tabindex="0" #firstElement>{{ 'news.title' }}</p>
<ul class="news-list" role="list">
  <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-1' }}</li>
  <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-2' }}</li>
  <li role="listitem" tabindex="0" class="list-item">{{ 'news.item-3' }}</li>
</ul>
```

Note:

- Focus can only focus on focusable element
- Be aware whether it's your translate pipe introducing timing issue, if you are using transloco may be try to use transloco structure directive instead of pipe.

Comment: @BálintBakos How did you solve your problem? Today I rethink, ngAfterViewInit should work fine even without {static: true} . `{static: true}` helps with query viewChild before DetectionChange, but you are setting focus afterViewInit, everything should just work. Did your translate pipe causes timing issue?

Comment: `cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture` is a lifesaver, thank you!